# Upload multiple videos from Ionic to PHP API

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic3, silex

i have an Ionic app that lets a user take 5 videos and upload them to my PHP API, the PHP API expects 5 videos in the POST request so it will generate a compiled one and send the link to it back to the user.

The compilation part in the API is working, i'm using POSTMAN to test it, but i cannot upload the multiple videos to the API.

I'm using Ionic Http Plugin's uploadFile method, i can upload 1 video successfully but not all the 5 ones, tried using a loop but it is not working.

Ionic Code (Ionic 3)

```
  let j = 0;
  for( j = 0; j < this.favorites.length; j++){
    this.http
    .uploadFile(this.apiLink+"user/upload",{},{},this.favorites[j],"file")
    .then(data => { 
      console.log("Data" + data); 
    })
    .catch(error => { 
      console.log("Error" + error);  
    });
  }}
```

PHP Code (PHP 5 with Silex framework)

```
$app->post("/user/upload", function (Request $request) use ($app) { 

$file1 = $request->files->get('file1');
$file2 = $request->files->get('file2');
$file3 = $request->files->get('file3');
$file4 = $request->files->get('file4');
$file5 = $request->files->get('file5');

$files = [];

array_push($files,$file1);
array_push($files,$file2);
array_push($files,$file3);
array_push($files,$file4);
array_push($files,$file5);

$rsp = upload($files);

return $app->json(array('response'=>$rsp));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$file1 = $request->file('dd_upload');
$file2 = $request->file('pan_upload');
$file3 = $request->file('aadhar_upload');
$file4 = $request->file('passbook_upload');
$file5 = $request->file('signature');

if(!empty($file1) && !empty($file2) && !empty($file3) && !empty($file4) && 
!empty($file5)){

$fileName1 = $file1->getClientOriginalName();
$fileName2 = $file2->getClientOriginalName();
$fileName3 = $file3->getClientOriginalName();
$fileName4 = $file4->getClientOriginalName();
$fileName5 = $file5->getClientOriginalName();

$destination = 'public/uploads/docs/'. Auth::user()->customer_id;

$file1->move($destination,$fileName1);
$file2->move($destination,$fileName2);
$file3->move($destination,$fileName3);
$file4->move($destination,$fileName4);
$file5->move($destination,$fileName5);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain this? My problem is uploading the 5 files to my Php Api